# How do I send bulk mails asynchronously in loop in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, asynchronous, nodemailer

I want to send multiple mails to users using asynchronously.

- user.js File

```
var emailUtil = require("./emailUtil.js");
var userdata[100];
        
// Suppose in userdata there are multiple data, let it be 100
    
for (let i = 0; i < userdata.length; i++) {    
    let emailBody = 'body of the mail', emailSubject = 'SGT Schedule';
    emailUtil.sendEmail(emailBody, '' , emailSubject, '' , '' , user_data.email, 'Your Name', '');
}
```

In the other file where I write my email sending function

- emailUtil.js

```
// Email Util File

var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
        
// Not the movie transporter!
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'email id', // Your email id
        pass: '*******' // Your password
    }
});        
    
module.exports = {
    sendEmail: function sendMail(varhtml,vartext, varsubject,varfrom, varfrom_name,varto, varto_name, reply_to_email ) {
        // setup e-mail data with unicode symbols
        var mailOptions = {
            to: [varto], // list of receivers
            subject: varsubject, // Subject line
            text: vartext, // plaintext body
            html: varhtml // html body
        };
        console.log(mailOptions);
        // send mail with defined transport object
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
            if (error) {
                return console.log(error);
            } else {
                return console.log(info);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I want to send the response immediately. I don't need to wait for the emails
So for doing that I am thinking about send mails using loop but asynchronously.

Currenlty, I am sending my response before sending mail and then just call the mail functions? If someone send another request to that api, then It will take more time than usual as node.js is a single threaded and this thread is waiting for executing its code (previous api call busing in sending mail) or it will not look at that thread by just creating of an another instance of that file

Hope I am able to explain my question properly. Please let me know if there is any concern

Comment: calling the sendEmail function while you go through a for loop (or any other loop) would do what you want. Fire all the mails as the loop loops (lol) and not give a crap about the transporter.sendEmail result

Comment: Currenlty, I send my response before sending mail and then just call the mail functions? I update the question for that

Comment: That won't work. If you have an async function like transporter.sendEmail you will have to implement callbacks or promises. Let me post an answer to examplify

Answer (score 0):

```
sendEmail: (somevariables balbla) {
  //some code
  transporter.sendEmail((err, res) => {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(res);
  });
}
```

This function can be called like this, in order to achieve the desired result:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  sendEmail(someParams);
}
```

It will be called a hundred times, not caring nor waiting for a response.
Now, if your email function was like this:

```
sendEmail: (somevariables balbla, callback) {
  //some code
  transporter.sendEmail((err, res) => {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(res);
    return callback(err, res);
  });
}
```

You can still call it with a loop and ignore whatever is returned by the callback. Same if your function is like this:

```
sendEmail: (somevariables balbla, callback) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //some code
    transporter.sendEmail((err, res) => {
      console.log(err);
      console.log(res);
      return resolve(res);
    });
  });
}
```

**tl;dr** call your function in a loop and it will do what you want. If you want you can have your function return a promise or a callback in case in some other scenario you want to wait for its result.

Comment: So it means I won't change my code as I called to my function and don't wait for response. Right ?

Comment: Yes. Still, your code has those return which will never work. You could do those modifications to return either a promise or a callback in case you need it in the future.